# jquery json parsing

Tags: jquery, json

I have a map with 4 layers, each layer having markers for various shops. What I need to do is this.

- User chooses shop from select
- Script grabs shop name and then finds the correct data for that shop from json.

I have a rough idea of how the script should look but don't know how to write it correctly.

```
$('#shopselect').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.txt",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {

    var selected = $('#shopselect option:selected').text()

    if ($(".layer1:visible").length) {
        $("#viewport").mapbox("center", { 
            x: shops." + selected + ".l1x, 
            y: shops." + selected + ".l1y 
        });
    } else if ($(".layer2:visible").length) {
        $("#viewport").mapbox("center", { 
            x: shops." + selected + ".l2x, 
            y: shops." + selected + ".l1y 
        });
    } else if ($(".layer3:visible").length) {
        $("#viewport").mapbox("center", { 
            x: shops." + selected + ".l3x, 
            y: shops." + selected + ".l1y 
        });
    } else if ($(".layer4:visible").length) {
        $("#viewport").mapbox("center", { 
            x: shops." + selected + ".l4x, 
            y: shops." + selected + ".l1y 
        });
    }
}
});
```

The json looks like so.

```
{
shops:{
    primark:{
        l1x:310,
        l1y:132,
        l2x:388,
        l2y:264,            
        l3x:530,
        l3y:355,
        l4x:670,
        l4y:450
    },
    boots:{
        l1x:310,
        l1y:132,
        l2x:388,
        l2y:264,            
        l3x:530,
        l3y:355,
        l4x:670,
        l4y:450
    }       
}
```

}

Is there anyone who could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using this :

```
x: shops." + selected + ".l1x, 
y: shops." + selected + ".l1y
```

What about something like that :

```
x: data.shops[selected].l1x, 
y: data.shops[selected].l1y
```

Comment: The JSON is in the function parameter data, so you'd need to use 

    x: data.shops[selected].l1x,
    y: data.shops[selected].l1y

Comment: @David : ergh, I focused on the syntax, and didn't check the variables :-( I've edited my answer ; Thanks for your comment !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the value you get in :

```
var selected = $('#shopselect option:selected').text()
```

(by the way you forgot a semicolon here) is either "primark" or "boots",
you should be able to access the data this way:

```
var coords = data.shops[selected];
if ($(".layer1:visible").length) {
    $("#viewport").mapbox("center", { 
        x: coords.l1x, 
        y: coords.l1y 
    });
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get the shops:

```
var shops = data.shops;
```

The correct way to get the shop properties is:

```
shops[selected].l4x
```

In other words treat shops as an associative array.