# Retrieving values from JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have been using this JSON

```
{ 
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "age": 25,
    "info": { 
        "email": "abc@abc.com",
        "url": "http://"
    }
}
```

With this jQuery function

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $.getJSON("demo_ajax_json.js", function(result) {
                $.each(result, function(i, field) {
                    $("div").append(field + " ");
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to extract the values of `email` and `url` from above given JSON. Can anybody help me in this regard.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery json parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386309/jquery-json-parsing)

Answer (score 3):

No need to do it in an each call.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $.getJSON("demo_ajax_json.js", function(result) {
                $("div").append(result.info.email + " " + result.info.url);
              );
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note that by selecting "div" you will be appending the info into ALL divs on the page.

Comment: i need to use each as the json file may contains data for more than one person

Comment: @h_a86 I see. You may want to update your JSON example then as the structure would have an impact on the proper answer.  In general terms your original solution just needs to go one reference deeper (i.e. field.info.email rather than just field.)

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
$.each(result, function(i, field) {
    $("div").append(field + " ");
});
```

With this:

```
$("div").append(result.field.info.email);
$("div").append(result.field.info.url);
```

You don't need the each as you're only returning one set of data and are trying to access it's properties directly.

Comment: Without the each call you will need to reference it as result.field.info.email etc., no?

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $.getJSON("demo_ajax_json.js", function(data) {
            var Append = "";
              for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
              Append +=title="' + data.d[i].FriendName + '";
              }
            $("div").append(Append);
          );
        });
    });
});
```